# Can't access Django runserver from URL or IP on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, django, nginx, ubuntu-18.04

I had a project that I transferred to Ubuntu with Git. Everything was working, then I updated some files and then it did not work. Being I am fairly new to this, I reinstalled the Ubuntu image on the server and tried again, still with no success.

I deleted my Django project `rm -r my_project` and created a brand new project on the server, both with Django 3.0.3 and with Django 2.2.9. Both have the same results. I loaded Nginx on the server and can get the default Nginx page from the URL and IP, but Django is nothing. Below are my settings. I tried with and without the firewall.

settings.py

```py
# Tried this
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# And this
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['my_domain','my_IP','localhost']
```

And then ran this from the virtualenv

`python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Which loaded normally and can be `curl`ed from inside the server, but

`my_domain:8000` and `my_ip:8000`

never connect and times out. I know not to use the Django server, but I can't get anything to work (gunicorn or anything other than Nginx default page).

**UPDATE**

After going through [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04gunico), it works now. Although the steps that it has you check the `runserver` and `gunicorn` before connecting it to `nginx` did not work.

Comment: Is nginx configured to serve the application?

Comment: What do the logs show? You should have setup logs for nginx, gunicorn and django and should look at those. If nginx fails to connect to Gunicorn, then you'll see something in your nginx logs, if gunicorn fails to start django, you'll see it in the gunicorn logs, if django fails to setup you'll see it in the django logs. Also when you say "nothing" or "no success", this doesn't describe the problem. Be specific. Timeout? Error page? Something else?

Comment: yes, time out. I will have to reconfigure gunicorn and nginx to get the logs. I had disabled them to try just the `runserver`. I will set it up again and get the logs and update the question.

Comment: If `my_domain:8000` and `my_ip:8000`  time out, then it could be a firewalling issue. It sounds like your next step is to connect Nginx to Gunicorn (on localhost or a socket), so you wouldn't gain much by changing the firewall to allow access to port 8000 from external IPs.